# Cross AppDomain "Cancelable" event

Tags: c#, .net, events, appdomain

I am implementing an application with multiple AppDomains. Most of the cross domain communication is done by using event mechanism. Everything works pretty well, except those events where EventArgs class contains properties with setter. Here is the example of the EventArgs class:

```
[Serializable]
public class CancelableEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public bool Cancel { get; set; }
}
```

Event is fired successfully, but if I set the Cancel property in second AppDomain (subscriber), it is not persisted back to the first AppDomain (publisher) after event execution ends. Is this behaviour by design, or am I missing something?

Comment: Please read my blog on cross-AppDomain Communication https://blog.vcillusion.co.in/sending-events-through-application-domain-boundary/

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of objects that can be passed between AppDomains: serializable and MarshalByRefObject.

Serializable objects (like the EventArgs in your post) are serialized in one AppDomain into some bytes represent the objects, and deserialized in the other AppDomain. It means that the other AppDomain receives a *copy* of the original object.

Besides, objects that inherit MarshalByRefObject can be passed *by reference* between AppDomain. If you inherit MarshalByRefObject instead of making your object serializable, it will probably solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Still hope there is some better way of doing this, but this is the workaround I have used:

```
[Serializable]
public class CancelableEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public MarshalByRefWrapper<bool> Cancel { get; set; }
}

public class MarshalByRefWrapper<T> : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not quite fully understand how it works.
But there are two items:

1. Inheritance from MarshalByRefObject (for Cross Domain)
2. implicit operator for EventArgs (for EventHandler)

At me it turned to transmit data, such as TypedDataSet and string

```
public class MyEventArgs : MarshalByRefWrapper<EventArgs>
{
    public DataTable SystemState { get; set; }
    public string SystemString { get; set; }
}

public class MarshalByRefWrapper<T> : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public MarshalByRefWrapper()
    {

    }

    public MarshalByRefWrapper(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public T Value { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator MarshalByRefWrapper<T>(T value)
    {
        return new MarshalByRefWrapper<T>(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of how your answer works, not just code.

Comment: Please read my blog on cross-AppDomain Communication https://blog.vcillusion.co.in/sending-events-through-application-domain-boundary/